# I have a select and it gets the options from the api, and it looks like this:

Tags: reactjs, sorting

I have a select and it gets the options from the api, and it looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypVpT.png)

Comment: What's wrong with that? please explicit your question. what you want to do? what's problem in your code? What kind of error in there?

Comment: i want this select option alphabetical order

Comment: here is my code....
<select className="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" onChange={this.handleChange} name="variants[]">
                      <option value="">{item.title}</option>
                      {item.variants.map(variant => (
                          <option  value={variant.id}>{variant.variant}</option>
                  ))};
                  </select>

Comment: please put your code in your question post

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.